# What CSS selector is this?

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

I've come across these selectors a few times and I'm hoping somebody will able to help me.

`.\36 785eb1b-7025-4977-bd8b-3639afbdb79a {
        fill: #1d1d1b;
      }`

Specifically looking at the `.\` part... Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's a class selector escaped (since the first character is not a letter). You may also write it as `[class="36 785eb1b-7025-4977-bd8b-3639afbdb79a"]`

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

Comment: AH! I'm assuming Adobe Illustrator adds these in, because the class names aren't set by the user, but rather as random strings.

Comment: @fcalderan Note that the space in the OP's example is a delimiter for the escape sequence, not part of the attribute value. So your alternative should not have the space.